# One submit button two event in Html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<button id="Submit" onclick= "write_task_content()"> Submit.</button>
```

I have this code written on my page for submit button. write_task_content() function is writing the activity of users into the file. I need to redirect to another page which is in another directory when same submit button being clicked.

**for example:**
Current path C:\xampp\htdocs\CC_real task\3GBCJUK5B10I32J9O2EJNNQ339GPKH.html where Submit is written. where write_task_content() function needs to be executed to save user activity and with the same button redirect to another page in the same window browser C:\xampp\htdocs\IA_real task\3RKALKFQG14FDCEAT1S123EW94A792. 
How could I do that?

Comment: You could make server do the redirection or use ajax to submit the form and once done, make a redirection client side

Comment: A very straightforward solution is to use `onclick= "write_task_content(); window.location = '/IA_real task\3RKALKFQG14FDCEAT1S123EW94A792';"`

Comment: I suggest to use anchorage link:<a href="/IA_real task\3RKALKFQG14FDCEAT1S123EW94A792" onclick= "write_task_content()" type="button">Submit</a>

Comment: you can use promises if you want to redirect after you're done with writing data to your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create your submit button:

```
<form action="destination-page.html">
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then, in the `<script>...</script>`, attach an `onsubmit` event to the form either using javascript or jquery:

**Javascript:**

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
form.addEventListener('submit',write_task_content,false);
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(
    $('form').submit(write_task_content);
);
```

When the submit button is clicked, `write_task_content()` will execute first and then the browser will request `destination-page.html`.

Answer (score 0):

After saving the details use

```
window.location = "http://www.example.com";
```

This redirects to another location.